# Heroku Discord Bot builds but doesn't work

Tags: heroku, discord-jda

I am trying to host a discord bot on Heroku (Discord JDA, Maven). I do this by connecting to Github and then deploying. The bot 'deploys' (view attachment) but doesn't actually work (view attachment).

What could I be doing wrong, or has anyone else come across a similar issue?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: how do you know that it doesnt work? where is the error? can yoyu show the log of the deployed bot?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty way to deploy it:

You'll need to setup a Procfile, extensive info on that right here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

The procfile is basically a file with no extension that tells the dyno how to execute your program.

A simple

```
worker: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar <PATH_TO_JAR>
```

will work fine if you don't need more config, refer to that link for more.

You can then deploy it like this (Good to have procfile and jar on the same directory):

```
$ heroku deploy:jar -a <YOUR_HEROKU_APP_NAME> --jdk <JDK_VERSION> --jar <PATH_TO_JAR> -i Procfile
```

Then to start it just do (Assuming you want a worker dyno, which is what discord should need)

```
$ heroku ps:scale -a <YOUR_HEROKU_APP_NAME> worker=1
```

Then stop it with:

```
$ heroku ps:scale -a <YOUR_HEROKU_APP_NAME> worker=0
```

I've found this is much simpler than using git, especially if you're doing tests or simple/quick stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Set up a Procfile. A Procfile basically tells Heroku what command to run when your app is deployed. Inside the Procfile, write `worker: node index.js`. Also, make sure Procfile has a capital "P".
2. Set up package.json.

   npm init

Then just skip through the set up and your file should be automatically created. **IMPORTANT**. In your package.json file, add your node and npm versions.

```
node -v
npm -v
```

Then go an type this in your package.json.

```
"engines": {
     node: "your-version-here"
     npm: "your-version-here"
}
```

3. Then try deploying your app to Heroku again. Also, make sure you have the "nodejs" buildpack set up for your app. Run it and test the discord bot.